# MultitpleOutputFormat - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Am a bit new to map-reduce so if anyone could guide me with the below question that would be great

1. I used Multiple Output format for writing to seperate output file in map reduce. Let’s assume my input file has Fruits and Vegetables and hence am splitting it into two files. Fruits and Vegetables as below.

   Fruits-r-00000 ,Vegetables-r-00000 ,Part-r-00000

   Am confused on how many reducers will run? I know by default the number of reducers is set to 1 and since the number part of the file name is same I believe only one reducer runs. Is my understanding correct?
   Also why does a part-r-00000 file get created? I write all my output either in Fruits file or Vegetable file.
2. If I have 1 GB of data to be processed, how would I decide the optimum number of reducers to be used?

Answer (score 0):

1.This output highlights one of the key differences between **MultipleOutputs** and **MultipleOutputFormat**. When using **MultipleOutputs** you can output to the reducer’s regular **OutputCollector**, or to the **OutputCollector** for a named output, or to **both**, which is why you see **part-nnnnn** files.

2.You can decide the optimum no of reducers based on **BenchMarking** with different number of reducers. It depends on the processing of data too.

Say for example we are going to process 1 GB with 2 reducers which yields a small portion of processing.But may be for other MR job we need to set 5 reducers for 1GB file which yields some sort of huge processing/calculation. So it will be better to set benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

```
one reducer will run ,it has nothing to do with part of file name , no of reducer would be either specified by the user by default it calculated the size of the input file and amount of work which need to be done in reducers .

part-r-00000 : This is related with partitioning, Since we have one reducer so all partitions will point to this file 

Number of reduces in most cases specified by users. It mostly depends on amount of work, which need to be done in reducers. But their number should not be very big, because of algorithm, used by Mapper to distribute data among reducers. Some frameworks, like Hive can calculate number of reducers using empirical 1GB output per reducer.
```